# How to implement functions declared in native code(C) with Java

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

everyone!
I want to know how to implement functions declared in native code with Java.

Now I have a dll file(and its source code) and a C# demo import this dll and do something.

```
    typedef struct
{
    /* Function used to open the communications connection */
    int (*OpenConnection)(void);
    /* Function used to close the communications connection */
    int (*CloseConnection)(void);
    /* Function used to read data over the communications connection */
    int (*ReadData)(unsigned char*, int);
    /* Function used to write data over the communications connection */
    int (*WriteData)(unsigned char*, int);
    /* Value used to specify the maximum number of bytes that can be trasfered at a time */
    unsigned int MaxTransferSize;
} CyBtldr_CommunicationsData;
```

Above is part of the code in dll file. In a C# demo, Above functions are implemented in C# and these four functions will be called in many other places in dll code.

Now I'm developing an app on Android and I need features the dll source code provide. But how can I implement above four functions in Android using Java and compile the source code to a .so file?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. Do you want to run C# code from Java? Why do you say "Above functions are implemented in C#" ?

Comment: Thank you for your response! I got a dll file and its code from a C# project. Code listed above belong to dll, but their(ReadData, WriteData...) implementation are in C# project. Now I'm working  with android and want to do similar job(implement these unimplemented methods use java)?

Comment: Look, I am very sorry, but I still don't understand. The code you posted is C/C++, not C#. You should edit your question.